# PHP: PayPal payment API not returning result?

Tags: php, paypal

I use the following code:

```
$enableSandbox = true;
$paypalConfig = [   'email' => 'test-facilitator@gmail.com',
                    'return_url' => 'http://test.com/paypal/?back',
                    'cancel_url' => 'http://test.com/paypal/?cancel',
                    'notify_url' => 'http://test.com/paypal/?notify'];

$paypalUrl = $enableSandbox ? 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' : 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$itemName = 'Call';
$itemAmount = 5.00;

$data = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = stripslashes($value);
}

$data['business'] = $paypalConfig['email'];

$data['return'] = stripslashes($paypalConfig['return_url']);
$data['cancel_return'] = stripslashes($paypalConfig['cancel_url']);
$data['notify_url'] = stripslashes($paypalConfig['notify_url']);

$data['item_name'] = $itemName;
$data['amount'] = $itemAmount;
$data['currency_code'] = 'GBP';

$queryString = http_build_query($data);

header('location:' . $paypalUrl . '?' . $queryString);
exit();
```

But after use, I am redirected to paypal.com home, and I am not receiving any error messages:

I also tested `test-buyer@gmail.com`, but it does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a copy of the resulting HTML that is getting output with this code.

Comment: Please share your HTML form code what variables you are sending ...then we can only help on this.

Comment: @AndrewAngell i have not html code, this code redirect automatic after user open my link

Comment: @RaghbendraNayak please check my comment

Comment: Are you able to login in PayPal after redirection and able to do payment as well ?

Comment: @RaghbendraNayak no, i redirect to paypal.com home

Comment: and there you are able to see the login screen to enter username and password?

Comment: No, exactly i redirect to this page : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/home

Comment: @Tooti Tooti: Please check my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code

```
$paypalConfig = [   'email' => 'test-facilitator@gmail.com',
                    'return_url' => 'http://test.com/paypal/?back',
                    'cancel_url' => 'http://test.com/paypal/?cancel',
    // Added new line
                    'cmd' => '_xclick',
                    'notify_url' => 'http://test.com/paypal/?notify'];
```

After `foreach` loop add

**Added new line**

```
$data['cmd'] = $paypalConfig['cmd'];
```

Then try hope it will work.

**Because you are missing :** `Buy Now buttons — <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">`

Please manage this and send `cmd` in your form-builder, it should work. Please let me know if not work.

Comment: See the paypal comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#hidden-input-variables

Comment: The cmd variable is always required in a FORM. Its value determines which PayPal Payments Standard checkout experience you are using to obtain payment.

Comment: Thank you, login form show to me after redirect to paypal